# Where to access/alter content generated by Joomla module

Tags: joomla

I have been tasked with adding a single link to a Joomla v1.5 site. For sake of brevity I won't include the backstory. Long story short ... this Joomla site is being replaced in the near future with Drupal. For the time being I need to add some content to the Joomla version.

I have a menu that consists of a series of `<li>` items that are hyper links to other pages. I can view the HTML source using [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) so I can see that the Joomla template code is generating.

The Joomla template code is ...

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu5" />
```

it creates the following HTML

```
<li><a href="/index.php?option=com_dmenu&id=35&mid=6">Link #1 Text</a></li>
<li><a href="/index.php?option=com_dmenu&id=36&mid=7">Link #2 Text</a></li>
<li><a href="/index.php?option=com_dmenu&id=37&mid=7">Link #3 Text</a></li>
<li><a href="/index.php?option=com_dmenu&id=38&mid=7">Link #4 Text</a></li>
```

I can view the module named **menu5** via the Joomla interface but I cannot see any way to edit the content it generates. I can change meta data regarding the menu (Title, Position, Order, Access Level, etc ..), but nothing about changing the content the menu generates. All I want to do is to insert another link in this list. I could modify the template and hardcode it except it needs to be inserted in the middle of the list.

Any Joomla gurus out there that could tell me where to modify the content this module generates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like it's a [Joomla! `Menu` module](http://docs.joomla.org/Menu) (in the `Module Manager` you can check the type column and see if its a menu type).

If it is a menu, you will need to use the `Menu` menu to select the right menu and then add a menu item to it. (Sorry for all the menus, it's a self referential subject).

Typically the menu module will have the same/similar name as the Menu it displays.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I looked at the menu manager and the type of the item "menu5" is "mod_menu5". So perhaps it is a custom module designed by the original developer. What a mess :(

Comment: No, that still sounds like a menu - in 1.5 when you created a menu you could set the type yourself.

Comment: Where do you go to change the content of the menu?

Comment: As I said in the answer "If it is a menu, you will need to use the Menu menu to select the right menu and then add a menu item to it."

Comment: When I view the Menu Manager none of the items listed are of type "mod_menu5".